# Eclipse IDE: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss-tools

I am working with Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0) and later to install the Plugin JBoss Tools, I observed that when I want to open a .xhtml file, the Eclipse give me the following error.

[image]

Maybe any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the eclipse documentation, I can see the Bug [574611](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574611) related to it. According to it, you can do the following to avoid the error.

1. Change the default browser to an external browser.

[image]

2. Change the configuration related to JBoss Tool Editor -> Visual Page Editor to open the .xhtml files with the source tab only.

[image]

I hope the post will be useful for us.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on MacOS with non signed binaries. See https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE-28007?focusedCommentId=19060991&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-19060991